# How to find implementation of OnAuthorization method of Authorize class or sample code for that

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authorize-attribute

I'm using `[Authorize]` attribute in my `Aspnet MVC` application, which redirects the user to login page when the user is not authorized. In some cases I need to redirect the user to another page(not the login page), So I just want to know how `OnAuthorization` method is implemented in `Authorization` class, so I could override it correctly.

Comment: What version of MVC are you using?

Comment: Assembly System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.2.0

Comment: Is [this](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/749384689e027a2fcd29eb79a9137b94cea611a8/src/System.Web.Http/AuthorizeAttribute.cs) what you were looking for?

Comment: That looks like similar, thanks a lot.

Comment: It is not similar, it is **the source code** for MVC 5.2.2. So if you are using `[Authorize]` - you are using this code.

Comment: Oh, sorry for that "similar", I didn't know, and thanks a lot. It will help me.